# .net remoting problem

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, remoting

I've got a .net 2.0 class library that uses .net remoting to communicate with a .net 2.0 server application.

I'm now creating a WPF version of the client and included the .net 2.0 communication dll.

The remoting no longer works (Exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0,)

the line that fails is passing a DataTable as a parameter to a remote method.

The problem is if you use .GetType().Assembly it really does show that it's using the .net 4.0 System.Data assembly  which the server obviously doesn't know about.

is there a way I can force the library to use .net 2.0 libraries for serialization?

Comment: Try changing the referenced `System.Data` assembly to that of version 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kinda depends on what type of configuration you're targeting, even if you run 2.0 and 4.0 in a mixed fashion this should be taken care by the run-time for you.

There seem to be a lot of components involved here, are you sure they are built using the correct frameworks?

If you build a WCF client on one machine and targets a different framework than the one installed on the machine that runs it it could lead to problems.

I'd like to know some more about your setup, specifically what projects you have and what "profile" these projects targets.

Meanwhile, you could try hooking the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and try locating the assembly yourself, it can work but it can also help to identify where in your code this problem occurs.

Comment: it's actually quite easy to demonstrate in a small project.

Create a new .net 2.0 class library, in the default Class1's constructor add the lines:
test = new DataTable();
string assembly = test.GetType().Assembly.FullName;

now create a .net 4.0 application and link to the library, instantiate the class and breakpoint on the assembly string inside Class1.

for me at least it says .net 4.0 even though the library is targeting 2.0.

Comment: This is how side-by-side hosting works. If you need to force the run-time to use a specific version add `<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /></startup>` to your `.config` file. This will however cause 4.0 components to fail to load, entirely. Take a look a the specifics http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx there are many different configurations that may apply to your situation.

Comment: Basically, I assume that .net remoting uses the binary formatter for object serialization and Type information is included in the message. What this means is that if you have a server application and a library that communicates with it using remoting all written in .net 2.0, you won't be able to use that library in your .net 4.0 application.

Comment: You know, just a thought but what if you resolved the types yourself? The AppDomain has an event TypeResolve (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx) which you could probably  use to redirect the serilization to use (or find) the correct type information. What happens if you just do a find and replace of `4.0.0.0` with `2.0.0.0`?

Answer (score -1):

looks like your application was created as Framework 4 Application.

Check the settings of the project.

Comment: Maybe you could give some details about "target framework" settings ?

Comment: The application is indeed targeting.net 4.0 but the library that the serialization takes place in targets .net 2.0. Have I totally missunderstood the point of targeting frameworks?